# Looking for a binary image layout tool

Tags: embedded

I am looking for recommendations for a tool that will let me construct a binary image out of a series of smaller images.

I have an embedded system with a flash ROM that I program using a single image.  That image consists of a series of smaller objects (data, compiled code, etc) placed at specific offsets.  The build system I inherited uses a disturbing amalgam of old 16-bit DOS utilities to hack the image together.  I was hoping to find a modern tool that would do the job in a less arcane (and less bug-prone) manner.

The tool needs to be able to run from a config file.  That is, I specify that file A.bin needs to be placed at offset 4KB, file B.bin needs to be placed at offset 16KB, etc etc in a configuration file so that the tool does not require repeated manual command-line invocations.  This is mainly because we have another system that will be auto-generating these config files.

The tool also needs to be open source (or at a minimum, cross-platform).  We have developers using Windows and automated build systems using Linux and the tool would need to work on both.

I have debated hacking together my own utility in C, but before I went through all the trouble developing and debugging I wanted to ask and see if someone knew of a tool that was already out there that I missed.

**Edit:** Cygwin-related tools are unfortunately not an option for us.  One of our critical build tools will crash if it is run on a system with Cygwin installed (I think it uses a specific, older cygwin DLL but that's an entirely different fiasco unto itself).

Comment: When multiple Cygwin reliant tools are deployed, and install separate incompatible copies of the tools or DLL on the same machine it often breaks.  That is why I worry when it is recommended without a health warning.  Many of the utilities you might want are available as native Win32 tools in either http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ or http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/, but I'd still recommend http://srecord.sourceforge.net/ in this case.

Comment: Try adding files with the same name as the DLL but `.local` added in the folder where the program and the (appropriate older) copy of the DLL is located. Should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually write my own, but via Jack Ganssle's [Embedded Muse](http://www.ganssle.com/tem-back.htm) newsletter No. 184 I came across http://srecord.sourceforge.net/ which will do just about anything with almost any type of binary image file (despite its name it handles far more formats than just Motorola S-Records, including raw binaries).  It may save you some time.

Comment: I'll second that recommendation. `Srecord` is a very useful tool for this sort of thing. I've used it on several projects; much better than what was done previously, which was to write a custom tool in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  `Srecord` seems to be a very flexible utility indeed.  It's not 100% of what we need, but I should be able to add in the remaining functionality fairly easily (much better than building my own from scratch).

Answer (score 2):

[dd](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html) would be definitively your best friend.

Use cygwin for windows users.

Comment: I thought about `dd` initially, but I would have to call `dd` once for each component added to the binary image.  Given the nature of the build system I've inherited, a tool that build the entire ROM image with a single invocation would be highly preferable.

Comment: Write a shell, python, ruby, or perl script that takes multiple arguments and repeatedly calls dd?

Comment: Cygwin just to run dd!?  A sledgehammer and nut situation methinks! ;-)  Only if you already have Cygwin installed I suggest; otherwise use http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: There are lots of options for dd on windows.  For that matter, it would be an exercise of less than a half hour to write your own tool for concatenating flat binary files with possible offset space between.

Answer (score 0):

The Elfweaver utility that is distributed with OKL4 may be appropriate for you. From the manual:
"Elfweaver is a tool that may be used to manipulate ELF files. Elfweaver is written as a Python 2.3 application that only uses cross-platform libraries. Therefore Elfweaver should run on Linux, Mac-OS X and Windows. The main functionality of Elfweaver is that it allows the user to merge multiple ELF files into a single ELF file"
http://wiki.ok-labs.com/downloads/release-3.0/okl4-ref-manual-3.0.pdf

If you think that looks suitable, you can get the tool along with the okl4 source code from the OKL4 website.